# Core Data managedObjectContext not being updated with UI changes

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, interface-builder, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have suddenly encountered a strange problem when making updates to core data objects using UI controls bound to core data NSManagedObjects.

Symptoms are as follows:
- An OutlineView displays a list of hierarchical objects
- A Detailed view shows the data fields from the selected object, these include text fields, dates etc.
- When updates are made in the detailed view these are reflected in the OutlineView (e.g. diplayName is used in the OutlineView).
- However when I save the changes the managedObjectContext tells me there are no changes to be saved.  So for some reason the UI is not letting the context know that things have changed.
- Given that the bindings are done in IB I assume that any changes in the UI would automatically be reflected in the managedObjectContext
- For some reason one of the fields seems to always result in the context recognising that changes have been made but not the others.  This one field happens to be a popup list containing objects from another entity in the core data database.

If anyone has any inkling on what could be causing this - is there any way to monitor when UI changes are made, for example changing text in a text field, and whether these changes are propagated to the managedObjects.

EDIT
Found the problem - for some reason I had changed some of the properties from @dynamic to @synthesize in the objective-c classes for the core data entities.  This was breaking things !

Comment: I think I have found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The IBOutlets need to be hooked up to the callbacks so that changes are known. They don't report changes unless you hook it up. So even though textField.text != oldText, it doesn't matter unless you take that update, save it to the entity, then see if it recognizes